# How to harmonize data inside FINAL database?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am testing Quickstart UI to become familiar with DHF.
In my understandings, default configuration have staging and final database.
Input flow will place data in staging, then harmonize flow will create harmonized data inside final database.

Now, my question is how can I apply additional harmonize flow against
harmonized data already exists in final database?

I know that writer module allow access all sort of functions
against final database, actually I could do whatever wanted in here on behalf of query console.
However, I think this should not be a right way, also even am successful
with data harmonization process(in database level), my trace records became full with errors.
Any advice or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer to run all flows from command-line, so I typically have a shell script that triggers the input and harmonize flows using Gradle. In there you can easily tell the harmonize system to use FINAL as both input and output. For instance like this:

```
gradle hubRunFlow "-PenvironmentName=$env" \
  -PentityName=MyEntity \
  -PflowName=myentity-harmonize-flow \
  -PbatchSize=100 \
  -PthreadCount=16 \
  -PsourceDB=data-hub-FINAL \
  -PdestDB=data-hub-FINAL \
  -PshowOptions=true
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very practical. On the otherhand, do you means that its difficult to utilize Quickstart UI for such case? I understands its not for production purpose, but also I would like to know how far we can go using Quickstart UI.